# SQL order by one column then group by another

Tags: sql

I have a table that has columns for id,category and position:

```
id | cat | pos
--------------
01 | ct1 | 2
02 | ct1 | 3
03 | ct2 | 1
04 | ct1 | 1
05 | ct2 | 2
```

I want to select the rows with the lowest position from each category. So from this data I should get id's 03 and 04 since they are position 1 from each respective category.

I have seen similar posts but with slight twists that make it hard to translate the knowledge, for example one suggested solution only has two groups so they have a fixed UNION as the selected answer which is way off for me as categories can grow. A decent explanation would be nice as I do not understand why the following doesn't work.

```
SELECT id,pos,title,cat,des,url,urltext 
FROM gallery_items
GROUP BY cat
ORDER BY pos ASC
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: Please Tag Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach uses a join to a subquery which finds the minimum position for each category:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM gallery_items t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT cat, MIN(pos) AS min_pos
    FROM gallery_items
    GROUP BY cat
) t2
    ON t1.cat = t2.cat AND
       t1.pos = t2.min_pos
```

Another way to do this would be via a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM gallery_items t1
WHERE t1.pos = (SELECT MIN(pos) FROM gallery_items t2 WHERE t1.cat = t2.cat)
```

Comment: Can you explain or link me to where I can read on which is faster and why? The query works as expected, however, I do not understand why the join/subquery is required.

Comment: the second subquery method does not work. This method is more along the lines of what I would expect logic wise so would be cool to see it working

Comment: 2nd one needs the from to be `FROM gallery_items t1`  the `t1` is vital.